# regex and replace giving &amp; instead of &

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this text `ijhhhv&yuy&uvuv&` and I want to highlight the "&" characters.

When I run this code:

```
var searchTerm = '&';
var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "g");
var content = "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>";
$('#div').html($('#div').html().replace(searchTermRegEx,content));
```

I get this: `ijhhhv&amp;yuy&amp;uvuv&amp;` - an extra "amp;" after my highlited "&", why? how to fix this?
(the search term is not just "&", I will use words and letters on my regex searches. I just got problems with the "&")

Fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Qhz/1/)**

Comment: Your source HTML is `ijhhhv&yuy&uvuv&`, but that is invalid HTML. In HTML text, ampersands must be escaped, like `ijhhhv&amp;yuy&amp;uvuv&amp;`. However, fixing that doesn't solve your problem, it's just a side issue.

Comment: It's not replacing, am I wrong?

Comment: @LightStyle: You are right. Using `&&` will simply make it replace nothing at all, leaving the content unchanged.

Comment: @Rikard, sorry I misread your post.

Comment: @mbratch, no problem. Thankyou for looking at it in the first place!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`, since the last one convert the special characters to valid HTML entities.

```
var searchTermRegEx = /&/g, //you can use short form
    content = "<span class='match'>&</span>",
    replaced = $('#div').text().replace(searchTermRegEx, content);
$('#div').html(replaced);
```

Your script works this way:

```
$('#div').html() // here it is ijhhhv&amp;yuy&amp;uvuv&amp;
         .replace(searchTermRegEx, content); //here it becomes ijhhhv<span class='match'>&</span>amp;yuy<span class='match'>&</span>amp;uvuv<span class='match'>&</span>amp;
```

If you use `.text()` `&` won't be encoded so the function will return the right (not encoded) text, that will be replaced with the spans, as you wanted.

Comment: You are right. It works great. I just need some minutes to read all answers and learn from you guys :)

Comment: This works for plain text with `&amp;` as the only HTML entity. If there are any HTML elements or other HTML entities, they will be lost or broken.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `&` characters in the string is HTML encoded, so the string contains `&amp;` for each `&` character. When you do the replace you replace `&amp;` with `<span class='match'>&</span>amp;`, so adding the `span` tag breaks the HTML entity.

If you want to highlight the `&` character, you need to replace the HTML entity `&amp;`:

```
var searchTerm = '&amp;';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [split the code into steps](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/dhP5m/) to see why this is happening.

```js
var oldHtml = $('#div').html()
```

`oldHtml` is now `ijhhhv&amp;yuy&amp;uvuv&amp;`. Since you didn't properly HTML-escape your `&`s, jQuery escaped them for you into `&amp;` entities.

```js
var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(searchTermRegEx,content);
```

`newHtml` is now `ijhhhv<span class='match'>&</span>amp;yuy<span class='match'>&</span>amp;uvuv<span class='match'>&</span>amp;`. As you can see, you split up the `&`s from the rest of the `&amp;` character entities.

```js
$('#div').html(newHtml);
```

Before it writes your HTML, jQuery fixes any bad escaping. So the HTML it writes will end up being `ijhhhv<span class='match'>&amp;</span>amp;yuy<span class='match'>&amp;</span>amp;uvuv<span class='match'>&amp;</span>amp;`. As you can see, the ampersands inside the matches are properly escaped, but the chopped-off leftovers of the character entities are still there.

[One way to fix this](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/bdB2c/) is to change what you're searching for. Since you're matching inside HTML, not inside text, you should HTML-escape what you are searching for.

```js
var searchTerm = '&amp;';
```

Answer (score 0):

The search term needed to be encoded.

```
var searchTerm = '&amp';
var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "g");
var content = "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>";
$('#div').html($('#div').html().replace(searchTermRegEx,content));
```